# Forigen Key not displaying in rendered model form

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I am looking for guidance on where I am going wrong. My model form is rendering correctly however the author has no option to select or input. I suspect this is is because the author is a foreign key. How do I get around this so the form will display a list of users or allow to manually input a name. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

models.py
class Post(models.Model):

```
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name="workout_posts")
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    featured_image = CloudinaryField('image', default='placeholder')
    content = models.TextField(default='SOME STRING')
    excerpt = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        # ordered created on field starting with newest first
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
class MakeWorkOutForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
def createWorkOut(request):
    form = MakeWorkOutForm
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, "add-workout.html", context)
```

html

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block content %} {% load static %} 
<h1>Create A Workout</h1>
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Are there any `Author`s in the database: if there are no such records, then you can not pick an author.

Comment: yes there is 3 when you go in view the admin log in. Its very strange i used the inspector and its showing a drop down menu with the relevant users but its weird why that's not being rendered.

Comment: can you share the HTML part where you render the form?

Comment: Sure thing ! ive updated the question body. Thanks